# Filter through an array of controls and manipulate them

Tags: javascript, refactoring, sapui5, logical-operators

Background : After reaching a certain state, the user should not be able to modify data in the form fields in UI.

There are less than 40 input fields that would need to be disabled once the UI reaches this state.

Currently, the implementation is to search through an array of all possible controls (array of 600), and the only ones that don't match the id of the controls in the condition get disabled.

Examples of `element.getId()` will be "`__xmlview2--SaveBtn`", "`__xmlview2-Page-SaveBtn`" . These are basically id's of the controls.

```
//for each control that is not the following controls perform the logic within this statement.

 controls.forEach(function(element){
    if(element.getId().indexOf("Page-") == -1 &&
       element.getId().indexOf("ControlName1") == -1 &&
       element.getId().indexOf("ControlName2") == -1 &&
       element.getId().indexOf("ControlName3") == -1 &&
       element.getId().indexOf("ControlName4") == -1 && 
       element.getId().indexOf("ControlName5") == -1)  {

            //do the logic fr disabling fields here 
     )};
```

What is the best way to write this code clearer so that it is obvious what this does? How would you do it? Thanks.

Comment: please add some examples of `element.getId()`.

Comment: Edited the question to add examples of element.getId()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to put the strings into an array and check agains with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```
var items = ["Page-", "ControlName1", "ControlName2", "ControlName3", "ControlName4", "ControlName5"],
    id = element.getId();

if (items.every(function (item) { return id.indexOf(item) == -1; })) {
    // do the logic for disabling fields here 
)};
```